# How to set Android BottomSheet expanded height?

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am creating a fragment button sheet and want to set the height is about 16dp from the top of screen.
[here i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgoKE.jpg)s the picture of the design and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeP2n.jpg) is what i've done

my bottomsheet fragment's oncreate

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val bsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_product_search,container,false)
    /*val behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from<View>(bsView)
    behavior.peekHeight=500*/
    bsView?.layoutParams?.height=800
    token = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(requireContext()).merchantInfo
    token?.let{idMerchant = ToolKt.getIdMerchant(token!!)}
    searchRecyclerView = bsView.find(R.id.rv_product_search)
    adapter = ProductSearchAdapter{item:ProductModel->itemClicked(item)}
    return bsView
}
```

here is bottom_sheet_product_searh.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/product_search_sheet"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_m_large"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_searchbar"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_back"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_large"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_large" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/product_search_input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/product"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image_close"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:contentDescription="@string/product"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"/>
</LinearLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_product_search"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:listitem="@layout/item_search_suggestion_product">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

as you see i set the peekheight but nothing happened. what is going wrong?

Comment: set Peek height to 16 like that

Comment: why is it should be 16?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use this layout ==> androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F7F7F8"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Buyer.ViewAllProductScreen">



    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#FFF"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/linking_main" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp">


        <include
            layout="@layout/sheet_main"
            />


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>




</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```